# CSS error width?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have the following issue:

[image]

I don't understand why if the input[type="submit"] style is deleted it keeps having 220px?

CSS code:

```
#popup_btn {
    margin:0 15px 0 0;;
    width:50px;
    height:40px;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Other CSS file:

```
.button, input[type="button"], input[type="reset"], input[type="submit"] {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
    border: medium none;
    border-radius: 0 !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 0.875rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    min-width: 220px;
    padding: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: none !important;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Maybe the wordpress does some stuff to it, but I can't understand...

Comment: But why? shouldn't `#popup_btn` be the one that it is used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be because you also have min-width set to 220px. Among,  no matter what you say the width to, it won't be smaller than 220px.  The solution might be to set width: 50px; min-width: 50px; wherever you want your element to be 50px